# node-horseman async not working?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, phantomjs

I'm using node-horseman to ( hopefully ) allow me to carry out asynchronous phantomjs operations to achieve async headless browsing.  The numbers in the array are at this stage irrelevant, I've just stripped the code down to the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem I'm having.

When I run the code below it runs async, however, as soon as I create a new Horseman it stops running asynchronously.  I know it is not running async because the outputs ( console logging the numbers ) happens in a linear fashion with each number being displayed after a uniform amount of time. Running it async it should be instantaneous as the overhead for showing each one should be the same, so all the numbers should appear at the same time the same way they do when horseman objects are not created ( as shown in the code below with the horseman object disabled ).

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var async = require('async');
var testArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
function evaluate( item ) {
    console.log( item );
    /*It runs asynchronously but if the two lines below are activated it
    stops being async and runs synchronously, defeating the whole purpose
    of using horseman??*/
    //var horseman = new Horseman();
    //horseman.close();
}    
async.each( 
    testArray, 
    function( item, callback ) {
        evaluate( item )
        callback();
    },
    function( err ) {
        console.log( 'all complete' );
    }
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code that you run with async.each is supposed to be asynchronous. If the evaluate function is not async the whole async each call is not async plus it runs the risk of producing a stack overflow error if the array is very long.

Comment: Ok thanks.  If I put the evaluate function inline on the async.each function parameter would this fix it?  Or are you saying that the new horseman is making it not async in which case I should create it outside of the async and pass it?

Comment: Just tried what I asked you and no it doesn't!!
`code`
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var async = require('async');
 testArray = [
     { number : 1, horseman : new Horseman },
     { number : 1, horseman : new Horseman },
 ];
        async.each( 
        testArray, 
        function( item, callback ) {
         console.log( item.number );
         var horseman = item.horseman;
      horseman
      .open( 'http://www.google.com' );
      horseman.close();
         callback();
     },
     function( err ) {
         console.log( 'all complete' );
     }
    )
`code`

Comment: Sync code can't be made async just by running it through async.each. Your async.each call is sync whether you have new Horseman in there or not.

Comment: Thanks, so just to clarify, you're saying that my code as shown in my initial question ( without the horseman ) isn't async?

Comment: @Michael 1. How do you know that it runs async or sync? Have you some indication of this by looking at the output? Please show the output and how you arrived at your conclusion. 2. What are you actually trying to achieve? What are those numbers and what are they used for in conjunction with Horseman? Please [edit] your question to include details. Comments are not well suited for posting console output or code.

Comment: Thanks, have done to answer your queries

Comment: Yes, your code as shown in your initial question isn't async. It just looks as if all the numbers appear at the same time because your computer is very fast. You don't notice a delay of a few milliseconds. Also it looks like horseman doesn't support async operations. So if you want to process several websites at the same time you need to use something else. e.g. https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom

Comment: Ok thanks.  I copied the code from an example of async node so presumed it to be.  I also wrongly presumed the selling point of node-horseman was that it bridged between phantom and node allowing async, without that what is its purpose?  Server side headless browsing?  

Also I tried node-phantom but being a linux newbie couldn't get it working correctly, will have to retry.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also having the same issues using async and node-horseman. If you use the .forEachLimit function instead of .each, you can limit the amount requests being done. I've opened an issue on Github about this issue as well:

https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman/issues/28

Comment: I switched to phantom-zombie instead as couldn't find a solution.

Comment: So .forEachLimit didn't quite as well as I wanted it to. Instead, I ended up using a synchronous for loop since node-horseman refuses to play nice with async.

Comment: Yes agreed, like I said phantom-zombie gives you async headless browsing though got that to work